# jQuery Deferred returns only last value in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, firebase, jquery-deferred

So I'm trying to go through one Firebase database to find entries in the database matching a criteria. Therefore I'm using the deferred object of jQuery to handle the database calls.

Once I get a return value from this first database I want to get the user info from a second database for each of those values in the first db. Then the results are added to a JSON array

so its:

```
<search for value, find one>
<<<search other db for oher info>>>
<continue search for outer value>
```

But this only returns one value - although everything else is running fine (and the console logs all the info correct).

Here's the code:

```
function find(searchLocation, profileID) {

var requestUserData = {
    data: []
};

var def = $.Deferred();

//This will be executed as long as there are elements in the database that match the criteria and that haven't been loaded yet (so it's a simple loop)
Ref.orderByChild("location").equalTo(searchLocation).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    def.ressolve(snapshot.val().ID);
});
return def.promise();
};
```

I hope you guys have any ideas on what to do or how I could solve this. Thanks in advance!

Edit: upon further testing I discovered that this problem already exists in the outer loop - so only the first value is being returned. I think this is related to the posission of the resolve() method but I didn't find a posibility on how to change this behaviour.

Comment: `notify` in the loop and `resolve` when it's completed

Comment: This leads to resolve() beeing executed before the first run of the query finishes so I get an empty object as a return val

Comment: To elaborate: Figure out the total length of the result set. `notify()` for each item completed. When you reach the total length of the set you `resolve()` the deferred object.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to figure out how to get the length of the result set in Firebase

Comment: It seems like a deferred is completely unnecessary here. This is an event handler for real-time streaming data, not a one-time result. For static snapshots, you want to use once('value') not on('child_added'). Also, there is an error in your code (ressolve vs resolve) which indicates it's untested and that the question lacks due diligence.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is a real-time database. The events stream as changes occur at the server. You're attempting to take this real-time model and force it into CRUD strategy and do a GET operation on the data. A better solution would be to simply update the values in real-time as they are modified.

See AngularFire, ReactFire, or BackboneFire for an example of how you can do this with your favorite bindings framework.

To directly answer the question, if you want to retrieve a static snapshot of the data, you want to use once() callback with a `value` event, not a real-time stream from `child_added`:

`Ref.orderByChild("location").equalTo(searchLocation).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    def.resolve(snapshot.val());
});`